# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The COM+ registry database detected a system error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, debugging

I'm trying to debug an ASP.NET webapp that's configured to "Use Local IIS Web Server" on WinXP.  When I start the debugger, the compile succeeds, and then the following error is displayed in a dialog:

> Unable to start debugging on the web
>   server. The COM+ registry database
>   detected a system error

The webapp never launches in my browser.  How can I get rid of this message and debug this webapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the usual stuff, and my exact scenario ended up being described [a post in the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/75b2e6ee-5b75-40f4-8c2d-5653a17b4316).  Its answer worked for me, despite my environment (VS2008, .NET 3.5) being more modern:

Here are the steps I followed (basically a summary of the link above -- "ASPNET" being significant because that's the user running the IIS instance on my development box):

1. Close VS
2. Shutdown IIS
3. Add ASPNET to the local Administrators group
4. Start IIS
5. Start VS and successfully debug ASP.NET webapp
6. Close VS
7. Shutdown IIS
8. Remove ASPNET from the local Administrators group
9. Start IIS
10. Start VS and continue debugging ASP.NET webapp without error

My development workstation's security settings/situation is regularly managed by our security folks here, so something must have upset my ASP.NET/IIS/etc environment.

Comment: When I rebooted, I got this error again.  I stopped IIS, added ASPNET to my local Administrators group, and the problem went away.  I stopped IIS, removed ASPNET from the local Administrators group, restarted IIS, and the error returned.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Visual Studio 2002 and I had the same problem, with tha same Error Message. To solve it, I did only the first 5 steps of the solution recommended before.

I am starting in VS 2002 because I use it in my work. I have the basic concepts, but I never develop in this program language, so I am a begginer.

The most important point in this solution I believe it is understand that ASPNET is a user in the development machine, as Administrator, as "Name.LastName" or any other user that access the machine. When I search for ASPNET to add in the Administrators Group and found it, made a lot more sense because I don't know exactly how the .NET architecture works.

So, if you have the same problem, I here confirm this solution solved my problem, even when I reboot my machine:

1. Close VS
2. Shutdown IIS
3. Add ASPNET user of the Machine to the local Administrators group
4. Start IIS
5. Start VS and successfully debug ASP.NET webapp

Thanks for the solution!!